# Wordpress Custom Vocabulary Multi-language

Tags: wordpress, plugins, translate

Our website needs to be translated into 3 languages - english, chinese & russian.
I have used google translate wordpress plugin but this was not accurate whatsoever - cn and ru did not make any sense according to our cn and ru personnel.

I am after a wordpress plugin that allows you to create our own vocabulary, without having to create a separate wp instance multisite..
Is there a plugin that exists as I cannot find?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin I have ever used and got positive result. Please try this.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpml-to-multilingualpress/

I am sure your problem may solve out from this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have got qTranslate plugin which works all ok, but only thing that does not work properly is Max Mega Menu plugin.